# Extracting Queryset with a Primary Key Matching a Form input in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I currently have a model which contains rfids and their correlating equipment.

**Model**

```
class RFID(models.Model):
    rf_id = models.CharField(max_length = 10,primary_key=True) 
    equipment_number = models.CharField(max_length = 11, default=0) 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.rf_id
```

I want to incorporate a form that allows for rfid input. The data given can then match with the primary key of the model (rf_id) and save the results of the query as a variable.

**Form**

```
class RFID_Scan(forms.Form):
    rf_scan = forms.CharField()
```

**Views**

```
from .models import RFID
from .forms import RFID_Scan

def latest_rf_scans(request):
    template = loader.get_template('metrics/rfid.html')
    form = RFID_Scan()
    code = RFID.objects.get(rf_id=rf_scan)


    context = {
            'latest_rf_scans' : latest_rf_scans,
            'form' : form, 
            'code' : code,

    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context,request))
```

**HTML**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}

    <h1>RFID Scan</h1>


    <form action="" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <table>
        {{ form }}
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
    <h1>RFID Scan Results</h1>       
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>RF Identification Number</th><th>Equipment Number</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>{{code.rf_id}}</td><td>{{code.equipment_number}}</td>
    </table>


{% endblock %}
```

I'm fairly new to this and I'm sure this is way off, but any feedback would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What problem exactly are you facing? Are you getting an error, or what is the output?

Comment: The form data gets posted to the server, but the query does not run.